# Formatting number in Python according to culture code

Tags: python, format, numbers, culture

Im trying to find a way to format number in Python according to the culture code used.

In R, for example, there is a function called 'formatC' that does exactly what i need:
if the culture code is 'en-US' the decimal mark will be ',' and the decimal mark, '.' (ex: 1,000.00) and, if the culture code is 'pt-BR', we would have 1.000,00.

Now, Im trying to do this in Python.. idk if there is a function that already does that... Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's built in 'locale' module. I would have a look through the docs here: [https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/locale.html), but for your example you can do something like this:

```py
import locale

#note the underscore rather than -
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR')

print(locale.currency(1000.00, False))
#prints '1000,00'
```

Using locale you will be able to format a wide range of values to suit specific locations, not just currency!

Comment: Hmmm, ive already seen this package but it only accepts 1 number at a time.. In my case, i need to convert a np.array of numbers

Answer (score 1):

You want the locale package, it has functions for doing locale specific formating:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html

Comment: I will try to take a better look at it! Thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

This is a function which takes the number, d1 =',' and d2 ='.' for example and outputs the number in the desired format as a string

```
def formatC (number, d1, d2):
    real_part = int (number)
    rest = str(number-int(number))[2:]
    real_part_as_string = str (real_part)

    k = 0
    result = ''

    for i in range (len(real_part_as_string)-1, -1, -1):
        k = k+1
        result = real_part_as_string [i] + result
        if (k % 3 == 0 and i != 0):
            result = d1+result
            k = 0

    if (not rest):
        return result
    return result + d2 + str (rest)
```

I don't know if this is exactly what is asked for because this returns a string.

[edited]

Formatting an array:

```
def formatArray (array, d1, d2):
    for element in array:
        print (formatC (element, d1, d2))
```

Example input:

```
formatArray ([1200.0, 12346], ',', '.')
```

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem.. In my case, i want to pass a np.array of numbers..

Comment: @HelenaFaillace I updated the answer showing how to use it on arrays. You can iterate through the array call this function and passing each element as an argument.

Comment: @HelenaFaillace I also updated the formatC function. This code works but It returns a string and not a number. It can only be used to display a list of formatted numbers as a string output.

Comment: Using your new code it works only if i receive on my list the number with some mark dots like 1200.0. But, if i only pass a link with the number 1200 it do not work as i aspect (1200 --> 1.200 or 1,200).. It returns me:
formatArray ([1200], '.', ',') -> .200

Comment: @HelenaFaillace Sorry I forgot to mention that I updated the original `formatC` function. Yes it has a bug with floats bu now It is fixed and both functions `formatC` and `formatArray` should work

Comment: @HelenaFaillace I tried `formatArray ([1200], '.', ',')` and It gave `1.200`

Comment: @HelenaFaillace Also I tried : `formatArray ([1200.0, 12346], ',', '.')` and it gave `1,200.0
12,346`

Comment: @HelenaFaillace Check the updated `formatC` function

Comment: Nop, it still doesnt work.. If i put 1200 it returns me ,200

Comment: @HelenaFaillace Post your entire code. the `formatC` `formatArray` input and output.

Comment: @HelenaFaillace I updated the `formatC` function again. Maybe the spacing was not correct. I tried again and it gave the right output.